# AVD rotates the screen when it starts without permission, here's a screenshot

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Here's what happens when I run the AVD:

[image]

And here are the settings of this AVD:

[image]

What should I do to get it right again?

Comment: It doesn't work. It just makes the window horizontal. I want it vertical, as it is, but also the screen vertical. :|

Answer (score 0):

Keep Calm and Use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com).

:)